# Play framework ClassNotFoundException with 'play run' but works fine with 'play start'

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I am running into some class path issues when I try to run the command 'play run', but when I use 'play start' everything works like a charm.

**Some background:** 
I am trying to create a Kafka Producer using Avro Serialization as a Play application.

I am passing the properties to the Kafka Producer using TypeSafe config library. A few of the properties are about the serializer class, key serializer class, partitioner class.

Folder structure

Base
- Controller
  - KafkaProducer
- Util
  - Serializer
    - class A
    - class B

package structure for the classes is com.abc.xyz.KafkaProducer, com.abc.qwer.classA etc.

I have verified that the respective classes are generated in the target folder.

I launch the application using 'play run'. When the producer tries to load the corresponding classes it throws a ClassNotFoundException.

```
! Internal server error, for (POST) [/publish/topic1] ->

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$2$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(routes_routing.scala:61) ~[na:na]
    at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$2$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(routes_routing.scala:61) ~[na:na]
    at play.core.Router$HandlerInvoker$$anon$6.call(Router.scala:170) ~[play_2.10-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at play.core.Router$Routes$class.invokeHandler(Router.scala:375) ~[play_2.10-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at Routes$.invokeHandler(routes_routing.scala:15) ~[na:na]
    at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$2.apply(routes_routing.scala:61) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.abc.qwer.classA
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202) ~[na:1.6.0_65]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_65]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190) ~[na:1.6.0_65]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306) ~[na:1.6.0_65]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247) ~[na:1.6.0_65]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_65]
[error] application - Error while rendering default error page
scala.MatchError: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError (of class java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError)
    at play.api.GlobalSettings$class.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:131) ~[play_2.10-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at play.api.DefaultGlobal$.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:189) [play_2.10-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at play.core.server.Server$class.logExceptionAndGetResult$1(Server.scala:73) [play_2.10-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at play.core.server.Server$$anonfun$getHandlerFor$4.apply(Server.scala:83) [play_2.10-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at play.core.server.Server$$anonfun$getHandlerFor$4.apply(Server.scala:81) [play_2.10-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at scala.util.Either$RightProjection.flatMap(Either.scala:523) [scala-library.jar:na]
```

When I use the 'play start'. Everything works fine.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.